# Наголос у слові "листопад"

Tags: наголос

Згідно з правилами української мови, наголос у слові "листоп**а**д" [на останній склад](http://sum.in.ua/s/lystopad).

Але все частіше я зустрічаю використання "лист**о**пад", навіть на телебаченні та в офіційних промовах. Звідки це пішло, і чи припустиме таке використання в офіційних/літературних ситуаціях?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Це двокореневе слово, "о" тут виступає взагалі сполучним голосним чи інтерфіксом, наголошують його у слові "листопад", якщо можна так сказати, через низький культурний рівень. Ми ж не наголошуємо у слові "снігопад" букву "о"? Так й з листопадом, тільки "а".

Просто так більш "по-народному", може та простіше казати. Це треба бути знавцем психології, щоб краще розуміти фактори помилок та мотивацію їх робити.

Наприкад, на [сайті](http://sum.in.ua/s/lystopad) словника української мови вживається тільки "а", як і на картинці [тут](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/nagolos/nagolos-u-slovi-listopad)

Comment: якщо відмовитися від оцінок культурного рівня мовців, то, на мою думку, зміщення наголосу відбувається, бо люди несвідомо намагаються таким чином відрізнити місяць (лист**о**пад) від природного явища (листоп**а**д)

Comment: На мій погляд, якщо масове використання протирічить академічним догмам, то це ознака закостенілості академічних догм.

Comment: Особисто я вперше дізнався про листо́пад з мови Ющенко. Після цього так дедалі частіше почали казати політики і держслужбовці з часів його правління. Взагалі наголос на передостанній склад — це особливість польської мови.

Comment: Думаю, Ющенко говорив листо́пад через те, що вчився у Тернополі, тобто на Галичині, де така назва місяця широко вживається. Я її змалку чув. Приєднуюся до цікавої думки дописувача Chizh, що мабуть хочеться підсвідомо розрізняти місяць і явище.

Comment: @Ukurainajin у випадку лист**о**паду наголос зазвичай не переходить на передостанній склад. як це було б у випадку польського впливу. хоча польською listopad звичайно має наголос на о, але w listopadzie переходить на a, чого я не спостерігав на галичині, хоча перехід 'с' в 'ш' ще зберігся деінде (скло -> шкло)

Comment: @АндрійБандура

порівняйте також кілом**е**тр та кіл**о**метр.

також такий незвичний наголос мені видається був притаманний вимові на слобідській україні. родичі розповідали, що мої харківські (харків, журавлівка, вул Ісаївська) прабабуся і прадідусь говорили таким незвичним чином. наприклад (іронічно) `да що ви таке гов*оо*рите!`

Answer (score 7):

Правильна [вимова](http://404.in.ua/2011/04/naholosy-v-ukrajinskij-movi/) — **листопа́д**. Підтвердження: [Вікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4), [Вікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4_(%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F)), [Мова](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/nagolos/nagolos-u-slovi-listopad).

Незважаючи на це, можна часто почути наголошення літери о: **листόпад**. Але підтвердження правильності такого звучання я не зустрічав, тож використовую саме **листопа́д**.

Answer (score 3):

Лист**о́**пад кажуть на Галичині, скоріше за все з розмовного галицького діалекту цей варіант наголошування й прийшов. Вплив галицького діалекту на совєцький літературний варіант мови (створений Олесем Гончаром) не має дивувати, бо саме в цьому регіоні українська існує як робоча мова в усіх сферах життя, зокрема Львів єдине в світі велике місто, де наша мова домінує.

Позаяк саме наголошення "лист**о́**пад" закріпилося в мовленні на центральному ТБ й серед перших осіб держави (політиків як то колишній Президент Ющенко), то мусимо визнати такий варіант нормативним. Ясна річ, що такої норми в словниках совєцької епохи не знайти, бо такий вжиток закріпився в публічному мовленні лише останні роки.

Comment: Це цікава відповідь і, що найважливіше, на мою думку вона відповідає дійсності. Я справді помічав, що у галицькому і інших західних діалектах частіше, ніж у решті України наголошують деякі слова на передостанньому складі (можливо, дається взнаки вплив польського, де такий наголос завжди такий), зокрема й «листопад». Але річ у тім, що на цьому сайті у відповідях прийнято не просто висувати свою позицію, а підтверджувати її джерелами. Чи Ви можете навести якісь джерела, які підтвердять, що наголос «лист**о**пад» більш притаманний (чи просто притаманний) галицькому діалекту?

Comment: @Sasha, я б сказав трошки інакше. Українській мові притаманний нефіксований наголос. На Галичині, В*о*лині, Поліссі й прилеглих територіях це збереглося, бо вони найменше зазнали впливу московської філологічної "правильності". Оскільки я покладаюся на те, що чую навколо, мені складно надати якісь документовані джерела. Ба більше - наші мовні джерела зазвичай слідують традиціям московсько-совєцької філології й не досліджують по-науковому питань як люди говорять і чому так, а лише нав'язують якусь "правильну" форму. Як бачиться, цим просякнутий і весь цей тред.

Comment: Насправді я особисто проти прескриптивного підходу (мовляв, «треба саме так і ніяк інакше»), я давно чекав, доки з'явиться хтось і аргументовано пояснить, чому «листо́пад» теж має право на життя. Але Вашій відповіді все ще бракує джерел. Наведіть хоча б посилання на відео з Ющенко, де він каже «листо́пад». (Зрозумійте — не те що я Вам не вірю, але якщо Ваша відповідь залишиться в поточному стані, то її можуть дуже скоро замінусувати.)

Comment: Я бачу в Грінченка твердження про те, що галичани взагалі вживають слово «листопад», а не про наголос на «о» в галичан.

Comment: @Sasha, зі [словника Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/26377-lystopad.html): **Галичане употребляютъ это слово для обозначенія мѣсяца ноября**. Желех. Словник Грінченка подає наголос на **а**, однак я живу у Львові й не раз чув, як львів'яни говорять лист**о**пад, що самому спершу різало вухо, бо я кажу листоп**а**д.

Comment: Так, я розумію. Але я прошу навести (якщо зможете) хоч якесь підтвердження, що наголос на «о» пов'язаний із Західною Україною. Мені самому теж так здається, але «здається» — то одне, а джерела — то інше.

Comment: @Sasha Мені не здається, я точно знаю, бо живу у Львові вже другий рік. Приїжджайте сюди та послухайте, як люди говорять - усе, що можу сказати наразі.

Comment: @Sasha, також, як на мене, некоректно вживати московський лінгво-симулякр "Західна Україна" на позначення регіональної культури. На Заході України є багато етно-культурних регіонів - Галичина, Волинь, Західне Полісся, Закарпаття, Буковина тощо. Усі з різними особливостями, зокрема в діалектах. Я можу говорити лише за Галичину, бо живу тут деякий час.

Comment: Дякую, я там жив якийсь час. Зрозумійте, я Вам вірю — але «своїми очима бачив, присягаюся» — необ'єктивний аргумент. «На Заході України є багато етно-культурних регіонів» — я знаю; просто в мене немає впевненості, що це стосується саме Галичини (а не більшого регіону), тому я вжив максимально широкий термін.

Comment: @Sasha, за моїми філософськими поглядами, об'єктивність має лише Бог. Я ж можу лише засвідчити, що у Львові, вихідці з Галичини, не зіпсовані совєцькими філологами кажуть "лист**о**пад". Вище в коментах люди також свідчили, що Ющенко, родом з Сумщини, підчепив цю звичку, навчаючись у Тернополі, який теж Галичина.

Comment: «Об'єктивність має лише Бог» — так, звісно, абсолютну об'єктивність — лише він. Але цей сайт вимагає трішечки більшого рівня відносної об'єктивності, ніж у Вашої відповіді. «Вище в коментах люди також свідчили, що Ющенко» — але вони не писали це у відповіді. Ви можете, будь ласка, хоча б додати посилання на відео з Ющенко у відповідь?

Comment: @Sasha, даруйте, коли відповідають на Ask Ubuntu чи Stack Overflow, то там діє за принципом "допомогло-не допомогло". А коли йдеться про мову, то тут багато важить суб'єктивний фактор. Я гадаю, моя відповідь допомогла ОП-ові, про що свідчить два голоси. Тутешня система голосування - дуже зручний спосіб визначити користь і потрібність, і доречність відповіді. Тим паче розділ у беті, тож ми частково й тестимо ті положення, які маються наразі. Як бачите, відповідь без посилань теж може бути корисною.

Comment: До того ж, чи не має моя відповідь посилань? Я посилаюся на загальновідому вимову екс-Президента Ющенка. Чим не посилання? Посилання - це не обов'язково гіперлінк. :)

Comment: «На Ask Ubuntu чи Stack Overflow» — там трішки інші традиції. В них сфера самом собою об'єктивніша, твердження легше перевірити, а в нас сфера — мова, і якщо не вимагати джерел, то такого можуть наговорити… «Посилання — це не обов'язково гіперлінк» — згоден.

Comment: Я тямлю, що наговорити можна бозна чого. Однак і за допомогою джерел можна вивернути все на догоду суб'єктивній позиції. Наприклад, в запеклому протистоянні совєцької гончарівки й класичної літературної мови в фонетиці гончарівці (чит. "сучасні філологи") мають фору, бо за ними всі офіційні джерела, а ми, на жаль, у творах класиків наголоси прочитати не можемо. Хіба у віршах, але й тут нам філологи скажуть, що це-ж-поезія, поет-ставить-наголоси-як-схоче. Я не знаю, чи Франко говорив "лист**о**пад". Може й ні. Але сучасні галичани говорять.

Comment: Це легко перевірити, приїхавши до Львова й поспілкувавшися з місцевими (не такими як я, а корінними галичанами). Якщо вам од відева з вимовою Ющенка стане легше, я постараюся знайти, коли матиму вільну хвилинку.